# How can I compress 32-bit/16-bit floats into BCn format texture without hugu float precision loss?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, rendering, textures, unreal-engine5

Recently, I do some research on compressing RFloat format rendertexture into BCn format texture. However, it appears that there is no direct BC compressed format available for 32-bit or 16-bit float compression.

As a result, I attempted to convert the floats to uint, split the uint data to fill the R8G8B8A8_UNorm format, and R11G11B10_UFloat format, and compress them into the corresponding BC format. Unfortunately, this led to significant loss of float precision.

**Quesition**: Is there any method to compress a 32-bit or 16-bit float format rendertexture into a BCn format texture while maintaining high quality?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built in that'll do it.  Can you post the code for your attempt?